# Remove multiple periods from a name in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table(Person) which have a column uploads contain uploaded document, that have the extensions like .docx,.doc etc. But some of the users enter documents like test.test.doc,test.test.test.docx, means multiple periods in a same name. I would like to replace that multiple periods to a _(test_test.doc,test_test_test.docx). Is it possible via SQL? any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Is there something wrong with having periods in a filename?

Comment: yes I have an application processing the same and got crash. As a work around we need to apply this for already entered values and also need to give a validation to prevent multiple periods in the file name.

Comment: You can't fix the application? OK.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a (rather complicated) way to do this:

```
DECLARE @DataTable TABLE(Data VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @DataTable 
VALUES  ('test.test.doc'),
        ('test.test.test.docx')

SELECT  REPLACE(LEFT(Data,LEN(Data)-CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(Data),0)),'.','_')+
        RIGHT(Data,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(Data),0)) Col1
FROM @DataTable
```

These are the results:

```
╔═════════════════════╗
║        Col1         ║
╠═════════════════════╣
║ test_test.doc       ║
║ test_test_test.docx ║
╚═════════════════════╝
```

And [**here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d60b/1) with a live demo of it.

Comment: Although you don't need the `,0` in the charindex, that's the default.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah, it's an habbit of mine to still put the `,0` on the `CHARINDEX` even if that is the default.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be shorter, but it turned out to be about the same length. Nonetheless, here is another way:

```
IsNull(Stuff(
   Replace(DocName, '.', '_'),
   Len(DocName) - CharIndex('.', Reverse(DocName)) + 1,
   1,
   '.'
), DocName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @DataTable TABLE (txt VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @DataTable (txt)
VALUES ('test.test.doc'), ('test.test.test.docx')

SELECT 
      REVERSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(txt, CHARINDEX('.', txt, 1) + 1, LEN(txt)), '.', '_')) 
    + REVERSE(LEFT(txt, CHARINDEX('.', txt, 0)))
FROM (
    SELECT txt = REVERSE(txt)
    FROM @DataTable
) t
```